# Connecting a java mobile application from a phone to a Server on a desktop through a modem

Tags: java, java-me

I am working on a j2me project i am currently using an emulator.Have managed to connect it to a java servlet but wondering how i will establish the connection once i deploy it to the phone.I am planning to use a GPRS modem to create the connection but I don't know how to.Kindly provide me with any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a data plan for your phone then you can use the J2ME [Generic Connection Framework](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/genericframework/) to make an HTTP connection.